# About pgfplot markers

Tags: pgfplots

Where I can find the complete list of markers available in `pgfplot`. I know that there is [pgfplot manual](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) , in which page 79-80 lists markers. But this manual does not include `halfcircle*` or `halfsquare*`. So I am guessing that there is a bigger list of markers. If such one exists, where can I find it?

Also, how do I define a `halftriangle*` marker?

Comment: There you have the manual of a really, really old version of PGFPlots (v1.3). The current version is v1.15 and the actual manual can be found on e.g. [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). In that the markers can be found in section 4.7.1 on page 182 where you can also find `halfcircle*` and `halfsquare*`. If you want to learn how to produce markers yourself, have a look at e.g. the TUGboat article of [Joseph Wright](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-pgfplots.pdf). Best of luck!

Comment: @StefanPinnow, please, convert your comment to answer or mark question answered by comment (not recommended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this answer doesn't answer the question totally, it was wished in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411247/about-pgfplot-markers?noredirect=1#comment1033688_411247) to turn my comment into an answer, so here we go.

---

There you have the manual of a really, really old version of PGFPlots (v1.3). The current version is v1.15 and the actual manual can be found on e.g. [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). In that the markers can be found in section 4.7.1 on page 182 where you can also find `halfcircle*` and `halfsquare*`. If you want to learn how to produce markers yourself, have a look at e.g. the TUGboat article of [Joseph Wright](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-pgfplots.pdf). Best of luck!